# This cancel button is not working, iOS7, Xcode 5.0 updated

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I currently am working on my user creation page, here's a picture:

[image: user creation page]

I need the cancel button to simply "popViewControllerAnimated: YES" to my login page. The User Creation page is embedded in a navigation controller, and that NavController has it's own top bar set to "opaque black navigation controller" and the user creation controller does **also**("Top Bar" in att. inspector set to "opaque black nav controller").  The UIBarButtonItem has this outlet -->

**@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *cancelUserCreation;**

and is connected to this IBAction
.h:

```
- (IBAction)cancelUserCreation:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
```

.m:

```
- (IBAction)cancelUserCreation:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Provide code if you can please.

P.S. The UserCreation page is embedded in a navigationController, consisting of three layers in the following hierarchy: **MasterView>ScrollView>ContentView**, where **ContentView** holds all of the objects in the view, and the segue from my login page to that navController is modal.  altogether, the transitions are: **LoginHomeViewController->modalseg->navController->embed->UserCreationViewController**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UserCreationViewController` is the root view controller of the `navController`, `popViewControllerAnimated` method does nothing. You cannot pop the last item on the stack.

call this:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I understand that now.  I want to do this programmatically. What method would I use to effectively transfer me back to my original login page?